# Zip 9 Check Constraint

Tags: sql-server

How do I write a check constraint for SQL Server that enforces the foramt "99999-9999"? This is to say, all 9 digits and the dash are required.

Comment: Did you try to write the code to check this?  You should edit to include your attempt.

Comment: You can do this with simple `LIKE` matching e.g. `CHECK (id LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')`. However that isn't altogether valuable, since people can still enter bogus zip codes that can't exist in reality.

Comment: While not answering your question, I have generally had more success keeping the postal code separate from the zip+4. I put the dash in place only when extracting the data out. In my systems, it was acceptable to have only the postal code. Plus the carrier delivery routes change much more frequently that the base digits

Comment: @AaronBertrand The purpose is to prevent completely absurd data from hitting my table. In theory address verification services have already been run, but I don't trust that to be the case.

Comment: So you still suspect you can have bad data in the right format. To me that still leaves you a step behind. :-)

Comment: How is the data getting into your table?  ETL?  Some sort of front end?  You'd be a lot better off trying to enforce that upstream of your database.  Also, you can download valid zip code data from various sources for use in cleansing data.

Comment: @Andrew You could make that same argument for never having the check constraint `Age > 0`.